# Writing data into an EMPTY(NEW) RFID TAG (Mifare one S50) with java smartcardio

Tags: java, smartcard, raspberry-pi3, rfid, mifare

I'm new at RFID Technology programming. I'm able to read the id of some RFID cards using the ITEAD PN532 NFC module connected to my Raspberry Pi; Here is the code I use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //initialization code
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        CardTerminals terminals = factory.terminals();
        List<CardTerminal> list = terminals.list();
        CardTerminal cardTerminal = list.get(0);

        //Card processing loop
        System.out.println("Terminal name : " + cardTerminal.getName());
        System.out.println("Card processing loop...");
        while(true){
            cardTerminal.waitForCardPresent(0);

            handleCard(cardTerminal);
            cardTerminal.waitForCardAbsent(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void handleCard(CardTerminal cardTerminal) throws CardException {
   final byte[] readUID = new byte[]{(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, 0, 0, 0};
   Card card = cardTerminal.connect("*");
   CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
   CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(readUID);
   ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(command);
   byte[] uiBytes = response.getData();
   String uid = bytesToString(uiBytes);
   System.out.println(uid);
}

private static String bytesToString(byte[] uiBytes) {
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   for(byte b:uiBytes){
       result.append(String.format("%02x", b));
   }
   return result.toString();
}
```

As I said, this works for some cards. But now i would like to able to write data to the EMPTY(new) RFID cards (Mifare 8k): to do it, I think the first step is to connect to the card then send the rightful APDU commands; but the connect() method gives me an exception when I swipe the new blank card:

```
javax.smartcardio.CardException: connect() failed
    at sun.security.smartcardio.TerminalImpl.connect(TerminalImpl.java:84)
    at rfidreadtest.RFIDReadTest.handleCard(RFIDReadTest.java:54)
    at rfidreadtest.RFIDReadTest.main(RFIDReadTest.java:42)
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: SCARD_W_UNPOWERED_CARD
    at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.CardImpl.<init>(CardImpl.java:96)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.TerminalImpl.connect(TerminalImpl.java:78)
    ... 2 more
```

I'm not sure, but I guess it is because the card is blank(I don't really know, as i mentioned I'm totally new and don't know much about that).

Is there something i'm missing?
what is it and how do i deal with?
Can you direct me?
Please help

Comment: don't think problem is that the card is blank. The card is detected as otherwise it doesn't get to `handleCard`. Could you try to forcing protocol to "T=1" or "T=CL" to check if this way works.

Comment: Hello @jlanza; I have tried both...I still get the same

Comment: "T=CL" is not supported..."T=1" produces the same result